# Waiting for a link to load [Selenium/python]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to load a page and wait for a specific link so I can click it, but I keep getting an error message:

```
      File "flychk.py", line 82, in <module>
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Current"))
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.50.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
      raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This is the link I'm trying to access:

```
    <a href="/FLY/USERS/user23/1454440494/">Current results</a>
```

And the python coded in my script:

```
currentResults = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Current"))
)
currentResults.click()
```

Comment: Is it taking longer than 10 seconds?

Comment: Nope, it normally takes 3-5 seconds to run. I've tried giving it more time, but the message is the same. I was thinking about locating it via the link path, but it changes each time because each time it generates a unique link.

Comment: Why don't you move the locating of the element outside of the WebDriverWait declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium is providing an interface as `javascriptexecutor`.

In java we are doing something like below:-

```
      if (driver.findElements("YOUR Locator").size() != 0) {  
          WebElement element= driver.findElement("YOUR Locator"));
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
     }  
      else{
          System.out.println("Element not present");
      }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
)

wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Current"))

currentresults = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Current")

currentResults.click()
```

Comment: Fixed the typo by moving the second closing paren to the second statement. Still getting same error though    **EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Current"))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.50.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:**

Comment: It's an issue with the page loading during the wait. It won't recognize anything. I've tried clicking on other links and tabs and it won't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted.
The simulation that ran as a result of the previous click opened and closed a new window, so window handling was the issue. 
Thanks guys.